# How to make a \upharpoonright longer?

Tags: macros, subscripts, letters

I would like to make a restriction to look more like

[image]

Instead of the usual `$b \upharpoonright_{\partial A}$` which is kinda small and doesnt go a little the base of the b letter, like a evaluated at would.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do you need a harpoon  for a restriction? The standard notation uses only a vertical line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with the `\scalebox` command. You can adjust the vertical scaling factor (`1.3`) however you wish. I also shifted the arrow downward using a negative value with `\raisebox`.

The `graphicx` or `graphics` package must be loaded to use `scalebox`. The usage is `\scalebox{horizontal factor}[vertical factor]{content}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\begin{document}
$b \raisebox{-1pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.3]{$\upharpoonright$}}_{\partial A}$
\end{document}
```